# Como consumir uma url JSON sem usar jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, get

Como poderia fazer para consumir uma URL com dados vindo de um JSON sem usar bibliotecas como o jQuery ou algo do tipo para uma estrutura do tipo: `[{chave:valor1},{chave:valor2}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos imaginar que você tenha um **arquivo.json** com a seguinte estrutura:

```
[
  {
  "nome": "Luiz Paulo Silva",
  "email":"luizpsilva@gmail.com",
  "idade":21
  },
  {
  "nome": "Pedro Felix",
  "email":"pedraofelix@globo.com",
  "idade":18
  },
]
```

E uma div para exibir seus dados:

```
<div id="view"></div>
```

Para consumir um JSON, sem usar o habitual `$.getJSON('...')` (do jQuery), você pode implementar um método em *JavaScript* puro através de uso de AJAX:

```
//método
var getJSON = function (url, sucesso, erro) {
      var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      httpRequest.open("GET", url, true);
      httpRequest.responseType = "json";
      httpRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (event) {
        if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
          if (httpRequest.status == 200) {
            if (sucesso) sucesso(httpRequest.response);
          } else {
            if (erro) erro(httpRequest.status, httpRequest.statusText);
          }
        }
      });

      httpRequest.send();
    }

//para chamar o método, faça o seguinte
getJSON('arquivo.json', function (data) {
        var view = "<ul>\n";
        for (var i in data) {
           view += '<li>Nome: '+data[i].nome+'<li>\
                    <li>E-mail: '+data[i].email+'<li>\
                    <li>Idade: '+data[i].idade+'<li>';
        }
          view += "\n</ul>";
           /* procura o elemento através da sua id
              e imprime o conteúdo */
           document.getElementById('view').innerHTML = view;

     }, function (errorCode, errorText) {
        console.log('Código: ' + errorCode);
        console.log('Mensagem de erro: ' + errorText);
  });
```

Comment: +1 sempre fácil em Jquery por ser menos complicado, mais achei legal em Js.

Comment: acho que vi uma implementação do `getJSON` similar a este hoje ;D

Comment: Estou compartilhando a mesma para isso. Me pareceu útil.